# Displaying Child item details in netsuite matrix item drill down template

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to get child item details on website built in NetSuite Site builder.
The Matrix page created have all parent item details, how can I get child item internal id based on matrix option selected.

Comment: what do you mean by `on matrix option selected` ? Please add some more details on your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Netsuite doesn't supply the child ids. What I generally do is send the parent id to a suitelet and return any needed child info as JSON. Part of what you return is the values from the matrix option fields on the child items so you can do your own lookup based on the drop-down values.

Comment: Can you provide me code snippet for JSON call. I will try to replicate same.

Comment: Thanks. It helped alot.